# Creating a path breadcrumb navigator control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

It's been a while since I've written WPF controls, so I'm looking for some guidance here.

What I'm looking to do is to create a control for displaying a directory path.

eg: 
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Next, I want to be able to do a number of things...

1. Hover over a part of the path and to have the path up to that point highlighted. eg: Hover over "system32" and have "C:\windows\system32" highlighted
2. Have text trimming work such that if the path gets long, or the container for the control shrinks, to display "C:...\drivers\etc". That is, trim the middle

None of the approaches I've tried seem to work well for me. I'd appreciate any help and guidance I can get here.

Comment: You mentioned in your question that `None of the approaches I've tried seem to work well for me` but you forgot to describe those approaches so that we could discuss them and be able to determine why they didn't work. It's kind of hard to be able to help in those circumstances.

Comment: Hi, There are open source BreadCrumb controls in codeplex. You can take some reference. https://breadcrumb.codeplex.com/